# How to Parse XML without using DOM or SAX Parser in Java?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, console-application

I tried to parse a XML file and write the data's in a CSV file without using DOM or SAX parser only by plain Java.

**Output should be in this below format**

Name | Age | Designation | Date | HomeTown

Steve, 21, Staff, 07/14/2013, California

John, 24, clerk, 10/17/2014, NewYork

Phil, 45, Principal, 08/20/2015, Cupertino

**My current Output format**

TotalStudent=3

Parent data :student1

Name=mick

Age=21

Designation=student

Date=07/10/2015

Hometown=Chennai

Parent data :student2

Name=Steve

Age=22

Designation=staff

Date=07/10/2015

Hometown=Cupertino

Parent data :student3

Name=Steve

Age=22

Designation=staff

Date=07/15/2015

Hometown=Cupertino

Parent data :student4

Name=Steve

Age=22

Designation=staff

Date=07/18/2015

Hometown=Cupertino

When reading the XML check for Total Employee count in  tag, if the total count is 3  and also total xml tags are three(i.e., the total employee details tag) then the three employee details will be write in CSV file in the above specified format and the CSV(date and time wise file name) file otherwise error log need to create.

I am not able to print the output in this format. Please help me to solve this and one more thing the code should be in O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity. If you paste your full solution instead of the method it will be helpful for me,

Thanks in advance.

**Here is my code**

```
public class Solution1 {

    public static ArrayList<String> attri = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> parent = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File xmlfile = new File("/Users/mani/Documents/workspace/XMLReaderWithOutParser/Sample.xml");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(xmlfile);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String xml_data = "";
            int nol = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((xml_data = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                nol = nol + 1;
                sb.append(xml_data);
            }
            String data = sb.toString();

            for (int i = 0; i <= data.length(); i++) {
                int end = data.indexOf(">");
                int start = data.indexOf("<");

      String attribute_data = data.substring(start + 1, end);
                data = data.substring(end + 1);

                String data_dummy = data;
                int find = data.indexOf("</" + attribute_data + ">");
                if (find > -1) {
                    if (data_dummy.startsWith("<")) {
                        parent.add(attribute_data);
                    } else {
                        if (attribute_data.startsWith("/")) {
                        } else {
                            attri.add(attribute_data);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (data.length() > 0) {
                    if (data.startsWith("<")) {
                    } else {
                        int filter = data.indexOf("<");
                        if (filter > -1) {
         String split_value = data.substring(0, filter);
                            value.add(split_value);
         System.out.println(attribute_data + "=" + split_value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error is :" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Sample XML file

```
<Employee>
<TotalEmployeeNo>3</TotalEmployeeNo>
<person1>
<Name>mick</Name><Age>21</Age><Designation>student</Designation><Date>07/10/2015</Date>
<Hometown>
Chennai</Hometown>
</person1>
<person2><Name>Steve</Name><Age>20</Age><Designation>staff</Designation><Date>07/10/2015</Date>
<Hometown>Cupertino</Hometown>
</person2>
<person3><Name>Steve</Name><Age>29</Age><Designation>Clerk</Designation><Date>07/15/2015</Date>
<Hometown>Cupertino</Hometown>
</person3>
<person4><Name>Steve</Name><Age>25</Age><Designation>staff</Designation><Date>07/18/2015</Date>
<Hometown>Cupertino</Hometown>
</person4>
</Employee>
```

Comment: It should be in O(1) space complexity, yet the first thing you do is read the whole file as a String in memory. Do yourself a favor, and use a real XML parser.

Comment: Out of curiosity; why do you want not to use DOM or SAX (or StAX for that matter)? Is it just for educational purposes?

Comment: I want to get the XML data without using any parser, that's why I posted  this question.

Comment: Negative voters - what is the rationale? OP has provided what exactly he is looking for and what has been done! Not using a real parser definitely is a bad practice, but you can't judge this question based on that!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, parsing XML by hand is nothing but inviting bugs and gotchas!.

Since you ***must do it*** without standard parsers and want a tailor-made parsing for a specific XML, here is something you could do to get rid of unreadable code(at least). Now, talking about O(1) space complexity. Assumption is that the XML is small and you are OK to read it fully in one shot; and then break the input,  there seems to be no way to have constant space.

```
    String[] persons = data.split("person[\\d]");
    HashMap<Integer, StringBuilder> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
    outputMap.put(0,new StringBuilder("Name | Age | Designation | Date | HomeTown"));
    for(int i=0;i<persons.length;i++) {
        if(persons[i].contains("<Name>")){
            outputMap.put(i + 1, new StringBuilder()
                    .append(persons[i].split("</*Name>")[1]).append("|")
                    .append(persons[i].split("</*Age>")[1]).append("|")
                    .append(persons[i].split("</*Designation>")[1]).append("|")
                    .append(persons[i].split("</*Date>")[1]).append("|")
                    .append(persons[i].split("</*Hometown>")[1]));
        }
    }
    Collection<StringBuilder> outputData = outputMap.values();
    for(StringBuilder output: outputData){
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Comment: @ ring bearer : Thanks dude, this is what I need.